# How to render a route on google map with lat long from previous page by html form?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, routes, draggable, forms, http-post

I want to render route on google map by lat long from previous page(send by html form)
and put the recieve value on php hidden type then pull value by jquery and define a start,end point
from value in hidden type finally call routefunction but it's not show the way route

I try to put alert in render section it's work fine but not show way route.I don't know why

This is my code

```
<?php
//get lat long from previous page html form
    $press = $_POST["send"];
    $lat1 = $_POST["lat1"];
    $long1 = $_POST["long1"];
    $lat2 = $_POST["lat2"];
    $long2 = $_POST["long2"];



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key&sensor=false"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">


    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
    var rendererOptions = {draggable: true}; //define dragble direction
    function initialize() { 
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions); 
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(13.76493,100.5383);  

        var mapOptions = {    
            zoom:7,    
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: center
             }        
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); //render map
       calcRoute(); //call route function
        }

    function calcRoute()
    {//get lat long from hidden type 
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var lat1 = $("#lat1").val();
       var long1 = $("#long1").val();
       var lat2 = $("#lat2").val();
       var long2 = $("#long2").val(); 

    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,long1);//define start point
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2,long2);//define end point
        var request = {    
            origin:start,    
            destination:end,    
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING  
            };  

        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) { 
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {  
                 directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);  
                 alert("DO");  //it's show alert when redirect from previous page
                }
            });
        });
    }

</script>  
</head>
<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:400px"></div>
<?php
    //put value from previous page on hidden type
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='lat1' value='$lat1'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='long1' value='$long1'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='lat2' value='$lat2'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='long2' value='$long2'>";
?>
```

Comment: Oh I can solve this.It's my fault,I',m forget to put 

   

      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);